# How to customize QListWidgetItem label appearance

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to label each QListWidget's item with easy to read description.
The text should be placed on three lines. 
First line is the name of the Item itself. And I want it to be bold.
Two other lines of text use regular font but both would start with a new line.

I tried to use:

```
listItem=QtGui.QListWidgetItem()

itemLabel='<b> Item Name </b>'
itemLabel+='\n Second Line'
itemLabel+='\n Third Line'

listItem.setText(itemLabel)
```

hoping to get things done with html tags. But it seems it is not working for me. Please advise

Comment: I guess you'll have to implement your own delegate for that.
Check the QT docs on delegates and e.g. the examples/itemviews/stardelegate.py in the PyQt4 installation for some ideas. You should be able to draw the item as a QLabel - enabling html text rendering.

Comment: @sebastian: I've been hearing on `delegate` "concept" quite often but never had a change using it. Would you mind posting an example on how to use it with this particular situation. It would be a great place to start!